# Bluetooth headsets can pair and work but cannot connect again

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, bluetooth, headset

I tried several new headphones (Airpods pro, Sony wh1000xm3, Jbl e25bt) with Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04. My PC is pretty new so no outdated hardware.

They all pair and work, but if I disconnect then I have to remove them to pair again. When I click to connect in the settings it just goes back to disconnect in a second.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. So, I turn off Bluetooth of the laptop and device again & then try to connect it. It works. Even if it doesn't work. I've to remove device from saved device list and pair it again.

Comment: It doesn't work for me and even if it works, every time doing this is really annoying. This  happens to me every time i disconnect not once in a while.